# MySQL connector timeout when opening the connection

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

I have the following class:

```
public class MySqlConnectionManager
{
    public MySqlConnection Connection { get; set; }

    public void OpenConnection()
    {
        Connection = new MySqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
        try
        {
            Connection.Open();
        }
        catch (MySqlException exc)
        {
            switch (exc.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    throw new Exception("Cannot connect to MySQL-server. Please contact administrator.");
                case 1045:
                    throw new Exception("Invalid username/password to connect to MySQL-server. Please correct data.");
                default:
                    throw new Exception("Unknown MySQL-connection error. Code: " + exc.Number);
            }
        }
    }

    private string GetConnectionString()
    {
        string activeDatabaseServer;
        string activeDatabaseName;
        string activeDatabaseUsername;
        string activeDatabasePassword;

        #if DEBUG
            activeDatabaseServer = DebugDatabaseServer;
            activeDatabaseName = DebugDatabaseName;
            activeDatabaseUsername = DebugDatabaseUsername;
            activeDatabasePassword = DebugDatabasePassword;
        #else
            activeDatabaseServer = ReleaseDatabaseServer;
            activeDatabaseName = ReleaseDatabaseName;
            activeDatabaseUsername = ReleaseDatabaseUsername;
            activeDatabasePassword = ReleaseDatabasePassword;
        #endif

        string connectionString = "server=" + activeDatabaseServer + ";uid=" + activeDatabaseUsername + ";pwd=" +
                                  activeDatabasePassword + ";database=" + activeDatabaseName + ";";

        return connectionString;
    }
```

When Connection.Open() is called, I get an timeout exception. Setting the timeout to 120 seconds didn't help. My debug database works (it's locally). I only get this exception when in release mode. But I'm sure that name of server, database, username and password are correct because I'm using the same database from another application written in php where everything is working fine.

The password contains special characters like '!', '%', '*', '.' or '@'. Does this cause any trouble?

Comment: Did you try to connect the Release Database Server in debug?

Comment: Actually I commented the #if DEBUG and ensured the release database is used.

Comment: As you said you can connect the the debug database when compiled in debug, if you just switch to release database, and see it can be connected, I think it would help you  to identify the problem.

Comment: The problem persists in RELEASE mode as well. The problem is about the release database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code runs on an external system. It's not possible to connect to a 1&1 hosted mysql-database from outside. :(